# Spark LuceneRDD - how does it work

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, lucene, apache-spark-2.0

Could you please help me to figure out what happens while initializing [Spark RDD](https://github.com/zouzias/spark-lucenerdd)?

There is an official example [here](https://github.com/zouzias/spark-lucenerdd-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/zouzias/spark/lucenerdd/examples/wikipedia/CapitalsSearchExample.scala):

```
val capitals = spark.read.parquet("capitals.parquet").select("name", "country")
val luceneRDD = LuceneRDD(capitals)
val result = luceneRDD.termQuery("name", "ottawa", 10)
```

But I'm not familiar with Scala and have troubles with reading source-code. Could you pls answer next questions:

1. How does spark-lucenerdd index `capitals.parquet`? How can I index each row of each column (all values)?
2. Can I set number of partitions for `luceneRDD`?

Comment: @Zouzias could you please take a look at this question?

Comment: (1) The index is multi-field, i.e., the indexing is done on both "name" and "country" fields. In other words, you could perform queries on both (or each) field after indexing. If you only want one field to be indexed, select only one.


(2) Is you want to set the number of partitions of `LuceneRDD`, you can do it on the input RDD / DataFrame / Dataset, i.e. `val luceneRDD = LuceneRDD(capitals.repartition(10))` for 10 partitions.

Answer (score 4):

(disclaimer: I am the author of LuceneRDD)

Take a look at the slides that I have prepared:

https://www.slideshare.net/zouzias/lucenerdd-for-geospatial-search-and-entity-linkage

In a nutshell, LuceneRDD instantiates an inverted index on each Spark executor and collects / aggregates search results from Spark executors to the Spark driver. The main motivation behind LuceneRDD is to natively extend Spark's capabilities with full-text search, geospatial search and entity linkage without requiring an external dependency of a SolrCloud or Elasticsearch cluster.

To answer your questions:

1. All columns of your DataFrame are indexed by default.
2. You can set the number of partitions by just repartitioning your input DataFrame, i.e.,

```
LuceneRDD(capitals.repartition(numPartitions=10))
```